# Fetch data from server using retrofit method

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i want fetch data from server, i have API URL like example : https://example.com/PlanController/getData/2/7k Plan, int his api url **2** is dynamic value and **7k plan** is also dynamic Value. i want fetch data from retrofit method. give me some examples.

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("PlanController/getData")
    Call<CoachListResponse> getAllData(); 
}
```

Retrofit clint

```
 public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define service after creating the retrofit

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("getData/{id}/{kid}")
    Call<CoachListResponse> getAllData(@Path("id") Long id, @Path("kid") String kid); 
}
```

```
 public class RetrofitClient {

        private static APIService service;

        public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
            }
            service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
            return retrofit;
        }

        public static void getAllData(Callback<CoachListResponse> callback) {
            Call<CoachListResponse> regionsCall = service.getAllData();
            regionsCall.enqueue(callback);
        }
    }
```

, consume

```
   RetrofitClient.getClient("https://example.com/PlanController/").getAllData(new Callback<CoachListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CoachListResponse> call, Response<CoachListResponse> response) {
                CoachListResponse responseDto = response.body();
              // logic
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CoachListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
               // logic
            }
        }, );
```

Comment: @LokeshGPLoki any luck!

Comment: i am getting null response

Comment: So the request is done and no response? of the problem in URL?

Comment: I got the issue just update `getAllData` to the new URL

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to replace only a part of the URL, and with this solution, I don't have to pass the whole URL, just the dynamic part and Your Retrofit client as it is no need to change:

```
   public interface APIService {

      @GET("PlanController/getData/{value}/{plan}")
      Call<CoachListResponse> getAllData(@Path(value = "value", encoded = true) String value, @Path(value = "plan", encoded = true) String plan);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting null respose, if i put hardcoed url its wornig fine..

Comment: try with this one **Call<CoachListResponse> getAllData(@Path("value") String value,@Path("plan") String plan)**

Comment: Anytime WelCome :) Can you please upvote and Accept my answer